# Scala Array.copyToArray source start index

Tags: scala

Can I copy from one Array[T] to another and specify the **source** start index?

```
val a = (1 to 10).toArray
val b = new Array[Int](8)
// specify target array, destination start index, and length.
// can i specify source start index?
a.copyToArray(b, 3, 2)

// b = Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0)
```

So, I can use Array.drop to get the desired behavior, however that seems inefficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `slice`?

```
val sourceStartIndex = 1
val destinationStartIndex = 3
val length = 2
a.slice(sourceStartIndex, sourceStartIndex + length)
 .copyToArray(b, destinationStartIndex, length)
```

It'll be more efficient than drop if `length` is small.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are looking for `Array.copy(a, srcStart, b, 3, 2)`